# cakephp rewrite rule for existing website with .htm

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, url-rewriting

How to fix my problem for an existing website converted to a cakephp application. The previous website has *.htm extensions. Is this something what needs to be done in the .htaccess file? The problem is that the website is of course in many search engines with having the *.htm extension, I want to avoid problems like page not found.

Example: www.domain.com/foodhabbits.htm  is now in cakephp application www.domain.com/foodhabbits

Comment: You can do it by .htaccess.. Just write a rule for files renamed and another rule for .html to non html..  example  Redirect 301 /foodhabbits.html http:// www.domain.com/foodhabbits

Comment: I do realise now that I still need to have my rewrite rules, otherwise I lose my position in Search engines. Thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `Router::parseExtensions('htm');` to your `app/Config/routes.php` file. The router will then remove the "htm" file extension and parse what remains, see also http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#file-extensions

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect solution. Just the cakyway, right?